# Keeping SEO rankings when moving to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seo, phantomjs, software-design

We are moving a PHP app to AngularJS and would like to keep our site rankings. Obviously we will use 301 redirects but do the major search engines keep SEO ranking if you move to an AngularJS frontend and use prerendered HTML? I just want to make sure that even if we allow the Angular app to be spiderable via phantomJS and prerendered HTML, we still keep our Google rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Most articles I have read, talk about [indexing an Angular app](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html). I assume that once you solve that you can worry about ranking. You are asking about keeping your ranking. If you keep your ranking, how would you make sure that your ranking is maintained.

**When to ask:**
You are asking at the start of the redesign which is excellent.
**Who to ask:** 
I am not in a position to recommend anyone but I found this explanation of what you are up against very helpful: [What are you going to do about Seo](http://www.angularjsseo.com/)

What I tell my clients is that they should not rely on programmers to do their SEO planning. You might find a programmer that is passionate about SEO and has a deal of knowledge about the subject but personally I believe that it requires another kind of professional that is dedicated and keeps track of google updates. Updates can easily outdate your previously chosen SEO strategy. Once you have a strategy in place, your programmer can get busy with url rewrites if needed. Your programmer has enough to worry about & a programmer != digital marketer. You are asking the right questions but perhaps to the wrong forum. [The world of SEO changes on a almost daily basis](http://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/ybabv/a_week_ago_i_knew_nothing_about_seo_heres_what/)  Perhaps the team doing Angular UI Router (not to be confused with original Angular team) can help suggest where to go.

Assuming you have changed your url, you seem to be on the right track:

> If there is one thing you need to get right during the redesign, it’s this step.  As I’ve explained already, you need to make sure all of your older pages 301 redirect to their newer counterparts.  301 redirects will safely pass PageRank from your older pages to the newer ones, and will enable you to maintain your Search Equity.  If you fail at this stage, your trending could very well look like the graphs I included earlier.  Don’t botch the 301 redirection plan.  You will pay dearly.
>   Read more at http://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-avoid-seo-disaster-during-a-website-redesign/42824/#6RCBeyeG5wHQW3l8.99

Lastly, [this article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/serious-angular-seo.html), explains quite a few options on how to get started with indexing and their conclusion is similar to mine:

> Although we present a relatively easy methods of creating SEO opportunities for our apps, it does take work to set it up and maintain. There are definitely professional services that offer SEO as a service.

We recommend one of our sponsors, brombone that has fantastic service and great service.